# Optmize server access for LAN and WAN (Internet Access)

Tags: networking, unix, solaris, wlan

I am trying to optimize my server so that accessing the local network as well as the internet.
The OS is Solaris 9 running on a SUN V210

Connecting outside takes a long time, with sometimes there is a failure in the connection. 
I get the following error

```
ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Then I try ping again after a few seconds.. ping is successful

```
ping www.google.com
www.google.com is alive
```

Entries for both default gateways in the subnet 10.100.x.x and 169.14.x.x are added in the outing table as well as /etc/defaultrouter

The connection is there but it is not stable, is there any way I can optimize this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to troubleshoot the actual problem.

If it says "unknown host", then you have to figure out why DNS isn't working sometimes.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea as to where to get started..links to any docs or information to share will be a good start for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm really sorry to say this, but if you don't know what DNS is, you are on the wrong site. Is this for a server at work? Get the IT Support folks to help you.